# how to compare two files using perl

Tags: file, hash, grep, compare

How to compare two large files using perl?
Using grep is very slow on large files.
eg: less file1 |grep -f file2 > file3
eg:
content in file1:
123;456;789
234;567;890
789;345;123
context in file2:
345
123
file3 output:
123;456;789
789;345;123
How to get the same output faster?

Comment: Your example is very odd. If you are comparing files, use `diff` or `cmp`.

Comment: As for your example, replace `less` with `cat` if you simply want to feed the contents of `file1` to the standard input of `grep`.

Answer (score 0):

Because it looks like you are searching for lines in `file1` which include one of a list of string literals given one per line in `file2`, try the following command line:

```
fgrep -f file2 file1 > file3
```